# Trying to enable passwordless sudo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, passwords, sudo

I want to enable passwordless sudo for user "bamboo" on my host, so I have added

```
bamboo ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

and also

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

(user bamboo is in the admin group) to the /etc/sudoers, logged out, logged in, but the sudo still asks for a password. I am on "Ubuntu 12.10" ... Any idea what do I wrong?

Thanks, f.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different mistakes in each line:
On the user ilne, you have not specified the COMMANDS portion, should be:

```
bamboo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

On the group line, you used `admin` instead of `admins`:

```
%admins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

From ubuntu forums I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43317/what-is-the-difference-between-the-sudo-and-admin-group) link which says:

> Administrators are added to the sudo group, but the admin group is supported for backward compatibility.

So you should have `sudo` group at /etc/sudoers and you should enable this line:

```
%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```